# How to update google sheets with google api using python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import gspread
import df2gspread

SPREADSHEET_ID = 'spreadsheet id'
RANGE_NAME = "A1:S3"



def get_google_sheet(spreadsheet_id, range_name):
# Retrieve sheet data using OAuth credentials and Google Python API.

global scopes
global creds
global store
global flow
global service
global gsheet

scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
# Setup the Sheets API
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', 
scopes)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
gsheet = 
service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, 
range=range_name).execute()

return gsheet

def gsheet2df(gsheet):
# Converts Google sheet data to a Pandas DataFrame.

header = gsheet.get('values', [])[0]   # Assumes first line is header!
values = gsheet.get('values', [])[1:]  # Everything else is data.
#header = values[0]
if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values)
    df.columns = header

    return df

global df

def Export_Data_To_Sheets():


    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=RANGE_NAME,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
    print('Sheet successfully Updated')



gsheet = get_google_sheet(SPREADSHEET_ID, RANGE_NAME)
df = gsheet2df(gsheet)

email_list = df
names = email_list['email']

for name in names:
name = 'test'
Export_Data_To_Sheets()
```

When I try to update/append a cell or cells in google sheets I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/FranEmails.py", line 167, in 
    Export_Data_To_Sheets()
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/AutoEmailScript/FranEmails.py", line 66, in Export_Data_To_Sheets
    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adaniels/PycharmProjects/EmailAutomation/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/13R_wIcWrX9Xa6ZURnLtuHK5czRfTKVakk6nOWkTjRqA/values/A1%3AS3?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `email_list` is a DataFrame so you cannot call the `spreadsheets` method like you can on `service`

Comment: originally I had service there, but it said service is not defined, do I have to call my other function in Export_Data_To_Sheets():?

Comment: Hello @YellowJacket, if you try to *update* a cell, since `email_list` is a `DataFrame` just like @Chris has mentioned, why don't you try to call the service but in the gsheet2df directly? Cheers!

Comment: When I call the service in gsheet2df I don't get any errors, but nothing happens. Is it possible to update a single cell at the time in the for loop?

Comment: Hello @YellowJacket, can you log the response of the request? Which code are you receiving? Moreover, what do you mean by "Is it possible to update a single cell at the time in the for loop"? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13 I ended up changing my code again to work outside of the other functions because that didn't seem to be working. Also what I mean by a single cell at a time is since its a for loop it would update after every instance of the loop. That being said I thought maybe there was a easier way if you were just editing a single cell in the google sheets. The new response I'm receiving is shown above in the edited question. I'm getting a authentication error and I'm not sure why. My google api allows for read and write.

Comment: Hello @YellowJacket, you should put your scope in brackets like this: `scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']`. Moreover, if you added new scopes or modified the existing ones, you should delete the already existing `credentials.json` file since it contains the auth for the previous scopes. Cheers!

Comment: Hi ale13! The script works and I ended up making two separate credentials files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `"Request had insufficient authentication scopes."` error is due to the fact that **the needed scopes were not found**.

In your case, you should declare your scope/s like this:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
```

If you added **any** new scopes or modified the existing ones, you should delete the already existing `credentials.json` file since this file contains the authentication for the previous scopes, hence the above error.

#### Reference

- [Sheets API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#notes)